# Force requests over https in Express/Node

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Express.js (v 2.5.8) (node v0.6.12) server running on port 3100. It is front ended by Nginx, which proxies both http and https requests to port 3100.

I want to force certain urls over https. Here's an example (app is my Express server):

```
app.get('/applyNow', ensureSec, secure.showApplication );
```

ensureSec is the function that I'm trying to use to check if connection is over ssl:

```
function ensureSec(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.ssl == true) { 
        return next(); 
    } else {
        req.session.ssl = true;
        res.redirect('https://' + url.parse(req.headers.referer).host +
        url.parse(req.url).pathname);
    }
}
```

The redirect works but node (after it times out) throws an error saying `Cannot GET /applyNow

What's the proper way of redirect to ssl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understand it, you are using nginx to negotiate SSL and proxying both http and https requests to your Express app. I would opt to solve this in nginx instead, if possible, but if nginx can't know which paths should be protected (i.e. only available through https) or you want to do this in your express app for some other reason, here is some information:

You should get the `X-Forwarded-Proto` from nginx, set to `https` only when the original protocol was https. Here's how you do this in nginx:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

I would also forward the `Host` header:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

In your express app, check for that, or redirect to the host in the headers and the requested path (express parses that to `req.path` so you don't have to):

```
function ensureSec(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] == 'https') { 
        return next(); 
    } else {
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.path);
    }
}
```

Comment: The X-Forwarded-Proto header was really a hidden gem. Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: In this case anyone can set (using postman like tool) header 'x-forwarded-proto' as `https`, but actual url as `http` and final response will be `http`. So is this secure ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure ssl port on your nginx server and proxy requests to node.js like other requests.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

No need to change node.js app. Just configure 443 port on nginx with your certificates and proxy requests to node.js app.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already doing so. I just want to protect certain paths. I would like to do so in the node app instead of in nginx. Doing so makes deployment easier.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Peter Lyons has said, express mandates that you run only one server on a port. If you try to run two http servers on one port, it'll throw an EADDRINUSE error.

Answer (score 1):

app.enable('trust proxy');

"Using Express behind a reverse proxy such as Varnish or Nginx is trivial, however it does require configuration. By enabling the "trust proxy" setting via app.enable('trust proxy'), Express will have knowledge that it's sitting behind a proxy and that the X-Forwarded-* header fields may be trusted, which otherwise may be easily spoofed."

[Express behind proxies doco](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#proxies)

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 different express `app` objects to do this. Each instance of an express server can only listen on exactly one protocol at a time. This can all be in one node.js process, but you need 2 differently-configured express server `app` instances, one for http, and another for https. See my answer for an example:

[How to force SSL / https in Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8634055/266795)

See also: [Automatic HTTPS connection/redirect with node.js/express](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458587/266795)?

Also note that you should not assign `req.session.ssl`. Setting that to true doesn't magically make it as if the client had connected with TLS instead of cleartext HTTP. It's a read-only property. Assigning it has no effect.

You should also note that you cannot run both http and https on a single port. That is why http uses 80 and https uses 443.

When you get the `Cannot GET /applyNow` error, that means that your express routes never matched the request path, and thus your `ensureSec` middleware was never called.

Comment: I'm using Nginx. Nginx can handle both the http and https connections so I can offload that from my app. I just need to force some paths to run over ssl.

Comment: Again, you need 2 different ports, and 2 different express app instances. Really. This can all be one node.js process and you can force some http paths to redirect to https, but you cannot run 2 totally different protocols like http and https on the same port at the same time. That's not a node.js limitation, it's how the protocols are designed.

Comment: Peter, as I understand the question, Rob has an nginx server in front, proxying the requests to a node.js server. So, to the express app, all requests will be http. But some paths, Rob doesn't want the express server to handle unless it was an https request (to nginx). I would suggest enforcing this in nginx instead, which seems much simpler. Also, my understanding is that Rob uses `req.session.ssl` to keep track of whether the client connected through https, which seems flaky (you need to reset that in the right circumstances).

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, the session value is flaky.

Answer (score 0):

As explained here: http://elias.kg/post/14971446990/force-ssl-with-express-js-on-heroku-nginx, with Nginx you can take advantage of the "x-forwarded-proto" header:

```
function ensureSec(req, res, next){
    if (req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] === "https"){
       return next();
    }
    res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Nginx on the front-end, the cleanest and most simple way to achieve this is to forward(rewrite) http URLS in Nginx to HTTPS rather than trying to redirect in Express.  This can be done as follows:

```
server {
  listen 12.34.56.78:80;
  server_name yourserver.com;

  location / {
      rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
  }
}
```

You can rewrite with this line:

```
rewrite ^ https://ducklington.org$request_uri permanent;
```

Just set up your location to match the routes or rules you need to forward to https.