# Force SSL with expressjs 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, express

I'm running a node.js express 3 server with no proxies and using SSL.

I'm trying to figure out how to force all connections to go through https.

Google searching shows me this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/express-js/Bm6yozgoDSY

> There's currently no way to force https redirects, though that seems
>   like a bit of a strange work-around. We have an https-only app and we
>   just have a simple ~4 line node http server that redirects, nothing
>   fancy

Which is what I need, but he doesn't say what those 4 lines are.

How do we do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I don't really understand the point in starting two servers when only one can do the job perfectly. For example, by adding a simple middleware in your server file:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
  }
  next();
});
```

This will redirect any non-secure request to the corresponding HTTPS page. For example, `http://example.com/` to `https://example.com/` and `http://example.com/foo?bar=woo` to `https://example.com/foo?bar=woo`. This is definitely the behavior I would expect. Maybe you should filter this by host, so it redirects only on domains for which you own and installed a proper certificate.

If your app is running behind another server like Nginx, you may want to add the configuration parameter `app.set('trust proxy', true)`. Or, even better, make Nginx do the redirect itself, which will be more efficient than any Node.js app.

**Edit:** According to my benchmarks, `join` is a little faster than `+` for concatenating strings. Nothing dramatic, but every win is a win...

Comment: I tried it and it seems like you still need to create a http server in order for this to work, basically 2 servers. Which is fine, and this answer works.

Comment: True. I meant two different pieces of code, sorry for the confusion. Or, only one app with some proxy server / load balancer =)

Comment: @prx The edit you suggested was rejected because it should be posted as a new answer rather than an edit to an existing answer.

Comment: For anyone using a newer version of Express (4.x) you will need to update the redirect to use `baseUrl` instead of `url`.  The line should read:
`return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.baseUrl].join(''));`

Comment: @Pierre this is working fine except for one case i.e. for the first time a computer loads the url without any prefix example "portal.abcd.xyz", in this case it loads http://portal.abcd.xyz if we reload the page it redirects to https

Comment: I don't understand the issue here. Do you have a clear case (as a new question maybe) I could look into? The prefix is merely a representation of the protocol ; it is never transferred to the server per se.

Comment: @Pierre I'm seeing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

You should create a second server listening on 80 and redirect with a 301 header to your https server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.redirect('https://' + app.address().address)
});

app.listen(80);
```

Comment: that would redirect all traffic, even existing https ones?

Comment: This can definitely work, but this approach doesn't work if the user requests another page that "/". In this case, he'll just get a disturbing 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the redirect solution is not suitable for me because essentially I want to get rid of the browser's insecure warning,

So instead of redirect every message, I did:

```
app1 = new express()
app1.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/redirect.html'));
```

});
  app1.listen(80, function(){'redirect server running on 80 port'})

and in the redirect.html is just a redirecting html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='https://my-site.com'" />
```

Of course, this won't work for complicated cases when you want to redirect all routings, but for me, I only want to redirect my homepage to my https homepage and get rid of the browser's insecure warning. Hope this help somebody!