# Force SSL on App Engine Flexible Environment Custom Runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, app-engine-flexible, metabase

We're running an instance of Metabase on a App Engine Flexible Custom Runtime with a Dockerfile based on openjdk:8. Currently it allows access on http://[metabase-project].appspot.com/ and https://[metabase-project].appspot.com/. I'd like to force SSL by having all http traffic redirected to https.

The Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 ./cloud_sql_proxy
ADD http://downloads.metabase.com/v0.21.1/metabase.jar ./metabase.jar
CMD ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=$INSTANCE=tcp:$MB_DB_PORT -dir=/cloudsql & java -jar ./metabase.jar
```

Our app.yaml looks like:

```
service: metabase
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

In a normal App Engine app.yaml file, I'd want to add:

```
handlers:
- url: [something]
  secure: always
```

But in the custom runtime we don't have access to handlers like this. Is there a way to configure the Flexible runtime to perform the redirect for all traffic?

Comment: Does your domain provider offer domain forwarding?  You can forward all `http:` to `https:`

Comment: @GAEfan this would only apply to a custom domain, and the project appspot.com subdomain would allow http without forwarding, right?

Comment: Correct, it would only work for custom domain.  I am not aware of a built-in for the appspot domain.  You may need to test the request header for `https`, and force your own redirect for non-https requests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

App Engine Flex doesn't support handlers, at all:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/upgrading#appyaml_changes

If you need https:// redirects, you need to do it from within your application.  Sorry!

Comment: Is that only with Java apps? Or with everything?

Comment: I did that in the app following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697660/force-ssl-with-expressjs-3, but I am getting "redirected you too many times.". I think the https is terminating on nginx itself and hence it always gives me protocol as http and secure as false.

Answer (score 9):

Late to answer, but I had to struggle a lot in order to do this.

I followed various links which mentioned the following code,

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
  }
  next();
});
```

This might work in other  cloud vendors.

But in GCP as rightly mentioned by @zengabor, our app will be running behind an nginx reverse proxy which terminates the SSL connection, we need to check the `X-FORWARDED-PROTO` which can be done by the following code,

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] && req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === "http") {
    return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
  }
  next();
});
```

Just adding my answer as after reading @zengabor's code I had to search again on how to achieve it. So above is the readymade code which will work.

Comment: It is important to use the status code 307 to work with methods other than GET:

`res.redirect(307, \`https://${req.get('Host')}${req.url}\`)`;

Answer (score 7):

Since your app (`env: flex` in app.yaml) is running behind an nginx reverse proxy which terminates the SSL connection, you need to check the `X-FORWARDED-PROTO` header which will be either `http` or `https`. If it’s `http` then you can do the redirect.

Comment: I am under the impression that I don't have the ability to modify the nginx config (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853799/is-there-a-way-to-customize-nginx-proxy-in-google-flexible-appengine).

I'm using Metabase, which has explicitly decided that this should be supported by the hosting platform and not their tools. They have a config for EB that sets up the redirect correctly (https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/1356), but it appears that there's no way to do with on appengine flex.

Comment: Since Metabase seems to be open source it is technically possible to extend it. :)

Comment: Confirm that "X-Forwarded-Proto" header is present today and either "http" or "https".

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me. In my case using Loopback based NodeJS application running in Cloud Sites App Engine flexible environment.

1. Create a middleware, for example `server/middleware/https-redirect.js` with the following code:

   ```
   /**
   * Create a middleware to redirect http requests to https
   * @param {Object} options Options
   * @returns {Function} The express middleware handler
   */
   module.exports = function(options) {
     options = options || {};
     var httpsPort = options.httpsPort || 443;
     return function(req, res, next) {
       if (req.protocol != 'https' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
         var parts = req.get('host').split(':');
         var host = parts[0] || '127.0.0.1';
         return res.redirect('https://' + host + ':' + httpsPort + req.url);
       }
       next();
     };
   };
   ```

   *(based on the step 8 in the post http://www.jonxie.com/blog/2014/11/12/setting-up-loopback-to-use-https-and-ssl-certificates/ but modified to use `req.protocol` instead of `req.secure`, also will only redirect if not running in development mode)*
2. Modify the file `server/server.js` to request:

   ```
   var httpsRedirect = require('./middleware/https-redirect');
   ```
3. An then, after the boot line:

   ```
   var httpsPort = app.get('https-port');
   app.use(httpsRedirect({httpsPort: httpsPort}));
   app.set('trust proxy', true)
   ```

Setting `app.set('trust proxy', true)` will let the req.protocol read the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.

References:

- http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#req.protocol
- http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html
- http://www.jonxie.com/blog/2014/11/12/setting-up-loopback-to-use-https-and-ssl-certificates/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
app.use (function (req, res, next) {
  var schema = (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || '').toLowerCase();
  if (schema === 'https') {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Node.js Express code I use:

```js
// set the env variable REQUIRE_HTTPS=1 to enable this middleware

.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    if (!process.env.REQUIRE_HTTPS) return next();
    if (req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] === "https") return next();
    if (req.protocol === "https") return next();
    res.redirect(301, `https://${req.hostname}${req.url}`);
})
```

Put it as the first middleware in your Express app.

This code assumes that you're using standard ports for http/https, as is the case when you're on AppEngine.