# How to allow only https traffic using a nodejs app on GAE flex vm?

Tags: node.js, https, app-engine-flexible

I have the following configuration in app.yaml 
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: app.js
  secure: always

But still I am able to access both http and https. I would like to disable all communication to http. Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: zengabor@'s post http://stackoverflow.com/a/43438781/3681767 covers this.

Comment: Thanks. will try.