# How do I disable AppEngine HTTP Endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine

I see that my AppEngine endpoint is listening to both HTTP and HTTPS, how do I disable HTTP endpoint?

- http://project-id.appspot.com - I want to disable this.
- https://project-id.appspot.com

Answer (score 8):

You cannot exactly disable it, but you can force a redirect to the HTTPS one.

If the endpoint runs in the standard environment you just need to set the `secure: always` config for the respective handlers in the [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_secure) config file:

> **always**
>
> Requests for a URL that match this handler that do not use HTTPS are
>   automatically redirected to the HTTPS URL with the same path. Query
>   parameters are preserved for the redirect.

If it's in the flexible environment things are a bit more complicated, follow this thread: [Force SSL on App Engine Flexible Environment Custom Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944776/force-ssl-on-app-engine-flexible-environment-custom-runtime)

Comment: Just to add a bit of information, in case you're using Java, you need to include a `<security-constraint>` element in web.xml file with a <user-data-constraint> setting <transport-guarantee> as CONFIDENTIAL. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml#secure-urls) you'll get more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deny requests over http (non-ssl) then check value for X-Forwarded-Proto header and respond with error if its value it http.

This header is added by GAE. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/reference/request-response-headers

> X-Forwarded-Proto [http | https] Shows http or https based on the
> protocol the client used to connect to your application.
>
> The Google Cloud Load Balancer terminates all https connections, and
> then forwards traffic to App Engine instances over http. For example,
> if a user requests access to your site via
> https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com, the X- Forwarded-Proto
> header value is https.