# How to forward http requests to https with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a webpack configuration of an https webserver. When an http request arrives, it just returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. How can I configure it to forward all http requests to https?

on package.json, the relevant script is:

```
"start:staging": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.server.stage.config.js --mode production --open --host 0.0.0.0 --port 443",
```

on webpack.server.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
...
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: '/',
        public: <my domain>,
        https: {
            key: key,
            cert: cert,
            ca: ca
        }  
    }
...
```

I tried playing with `proxy` options but couldn't make it to work.
Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need a second server that listens on port 80 and redirects the requests.

Comment: i think its not possible via [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1751), you may want to try this via [apache or ngnix](https://serverguy.com/security/redirect-http-to-https/)

Comment: @ChrisG is it something I can achieve with configuration only? or do I need to explicitly create a new webserver for this?

Comment: Forwarding (as in proxying) HTTP to HTTPS completely negates any advantage of HTTPS and adds pointless complexity and overhead. So I assume you actually want *redirection*, which forces the client to retry the request against different URL (in this case HTTPS instead of HTTP). The question arises though: why don't you resolve the issue on the client side to begin with? Why can't he connect via HTTPS from the start?

Comment: @freakish My intention is to handle the situation where a user explicitly tries to connect via HTTP

Comment: @Shirkan that's confusing: why would he do that? And even if he does then `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is quite self explanatory. Well, I suppose 30x codes do give more explanation.

Comment: @freakish redirecting HTTP to HTTPS is what you want to do as a service owner and pretty much an industry standard. How would you solve this on the client side? Each user types in whatever they want in their browser and you have no control over that. Having the user go to a blank page that says "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" would be confusing and might lead people to think the site is down.

Comment: "Forwarding (as in proxying) HTTP to HTTPS completely negates any advantage of HTTPS and adds pointless complexity and overhead." how is this possibly true?

Comment: @NicolaPedretti the word "forwarding" to me means: I take (as a server) http request, forward it over https to another server, get https response and send it back over http. Also known as [downgrade attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downgrade_attack). The best solution is to never let users connect via http. The second best to redirect to https on every http request.

Comment: What you are describing is not redirecting HTTP to HTTPS. You are descirbing a proxy that communicates over HTTP with its clients and uses HTTPS to communicate with other servers. Redirecting to HTTPS means redirecting the request coming in to HTTPS which normally involves sending back an HTTP 'redirect' paramater that tells the client to go to the same url but in "HTTPS".

Comment: @NicolaPedretti the OP used words "forward" and "proxy", and never used the word "redirection". Btw I believe I already explained that in my previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need a second server that listens on port 80 and redirects the requests. – Chris G

Investigated some more and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697660/force-ssl-with-expressjs-3) to be the answer:

```
const express = require('express');

// Forward http requests to https
var app = express();
app.listen(80);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.secure) {
        return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
    }
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that webpack have issue for this feature. Just linking it for anybody who would come here https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/126.