# How do I setup a SSL certificate for an express.js server?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl-certificate

Before, in an older version of express, I could do this:

```
express.createServer({key:'keyFile', cert:'certFile'});
```

However, in newer versions of express this no longer works:

```
var app = express();
```

Should I call `app.use()` to set the certs? If so how?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

See [the Express docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen) as well as the [Node docs for https.createServer](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) (which is what express recommends to use):

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync( 'privatekey.pem' );
var certificate = fs.readFileSync( 'certificate.pem' );

https.createServer({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}, app).listen(port);
```

Other options for createServer are at: http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener

Comment: Hmmm from node: https.createServer(options, [requestListener])

so passing app is ok?  isn't that app is an 'object'...

Comment: what is the function signature for 'app'?  i try to look up on github for express but i don't see that it takes (req, res)

Comment: Take a look at the definition of `createServer` in `connect.js` (express just inherits this from connect). You'll see that it returns a function with the correct signature. `connect()` is simply an alias for `connect.createServer()` and therefore so is `express()` (which probably does some extra initialization, but the result is still a function appropriate for use as a request handler).

Comment: -1, what library? Explanation as to what `app` is? Pasting a single line of code isn't concise *or* clear.

Comment: @Qix - in the OPs example, `app` is defined. This answer is satisfactory.

Comment: I've added some useful links to official docs for the answer, for my own reference as well as yours.

Comment: app is what is return by this in Node.js - require('express')()

Comment: is there any outline how to obtain the .pem files? I have two .crt files from my cert provider.

Comment: I was successful using key and crt files (instead of pem).  I got them via the process described here:  https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Fixing-Chrome-missing_subjectAltName-selfsigned-cert-openssl/ , but I had to s/-config <( cat server.csr.cnf )/-config server.csr.cnf/ and then bumble about a while to figure out how to add my root certificate (which was a PEM file) to my list of trusted providers.  Of course, if you are using a signed certificate from a common authority, you won't need to do any of this.  Main point is that the server works with key/crt files as well as pem.

Answer (score 129):

I was able to get SSL working with the following boilerplate code:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    https = require('https'),
    express = require('express');

var port = 8000;

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/privatekey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate.pem'),
};

var app = express();

var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
});
```

Comment: How do you actually see the hello world on the browser?
https://127.0.0.1:8000/ gives me a Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

Comment: upvoted too soon. I get --
Error: addListener only takes instances of Function

Comment: keep in mind that was written quite a while ago. It is possible this no longer works in newer versions of Express or Node.js

Comment: This is years too late, but the SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR can be caused by the fact that you're using http://<ssl_enabled_endpoint>. It should be https://<ssl_enabled_endpoint>

Answer (score 13):

This is my ***working code*** for ***express 4.0***.

express 4.0 is very different from 3.0 and others.

4.0 you have /bin/www file, which you are going to add https here.

"npm start" is standard way you start express 4.0 server.

readFileSync() function should use ***__dirname*** get current directory

while require() ***use ./*** refer to current directory.

***First you put private.key and public.cert file under /bin folder, 
It is same folder as WWW file***.

no such directory found error:

```
  key: fs.readFileSync('../private.key'),

  cert: fs.readFileSync('../public.cert')
```

error, no such directory found

```
  key: fs.readFileSync('./private.key'),

  cert: fs.readFileSync('./public.cert')
```

***Working code should be***

```
key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/private.key', 'utf8'),

cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public.cert', 'utf8')
```

***Complete https code is:***

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

// readFileSync function must use __dirname get current directory
// require use ./ refer to current directory.

const options = {
   key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/private.key', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public.cert', 'utf8')
};


 // Create HTTPs server.

 var server = https.createServer(options, app);
```

Comment: How would this work with a web-server-1 and web-server-2 with 1 load balancer?

The SSL cert is stored on the load balaner, which means the path to the certs does not work?

Comment: If you have a load balancer, then it should terminate the TLS (as it holds the certificates). At that point, you just need to serve yo a normal http app, with no concerns of SSL @iiiml0sto1

Comment: There is no `express = require('express')` anywhere here - so how is it working?

Comment: unfortunately this answer is very out of date. it's now trivial to do this.

Answer (score 0):

## 2024, it's now incredibly simple to get a LetsCreate cert:

1. Stop your webserver for a minute.
2. type

`% certbot certonly --standalone`

It will ask your email and the domain name. It will spit out the file locations

```
const cts = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/-blah-/fullchain.pem"),
    key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/-blah-/privkey.pem")
}
```

## Launch https server:

```
app = express()
app.use .. etc etc
app.get .. etc etc
https.createServer(cts, app).listen(443)
```

That's the whole thing.

## HUGE tip for ssl socket servers:

All non-trivial sites will have a few socket servers on different ports, as well as the web servers.

The secret is you simply add (ie, one line of code) a https server ***specifically for each wss server***.
(Full [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78069130/294884).)

```
// create https SPECIFICALLY FOR wss 7788
let for_7788 = https.createServer(options).listen(7788)
let wss = new WSServer({ server: for_7788 })
wss.on( etc etc )
```