# SSL on Apache with Nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, apache, ssl

I am working on Application with nodejs and PHP along with Mysql

PHP is **frontend** here,  nodejs is **backend**

Now

I created a form and while creating a form

i am sending ajax request to Nodejs

like

**url: http://example.com:8124/sign_in**

Which is working fine

Now Problem is that

When i enabled ssl on Apache.

now i am unable to send request to Node .

it is giving me error, like

Cross-origin policy , load unsafe content

How to resolve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's not a problem with PHP, rather with JavaScript (AJAX). It's because you're trying to load contents from a server that doesn't use SSL from a web page served via SSL.

Simply enable SSL also on the Node app and it will work.

#### Edit

I do not recommend creating a proxy server in Node.js.
It's actually a good idea to create a proxy server *in front of* every Node.js app. Indeed, for safety reasons most websites built with Node.js have a Nginx reverse-proxy in front. That is: users connect to Nginx (chosen over Apache for the much better performances) and Nginx makes a request to the Node.js app.
With this setup, you would actually not need to enable SSL in Node.js, as long as Nginx has SSL enabled.

To use SSL directly in Node.js, you need to add just a couple of lines to your app.js file. See this SO question: [How do I setup a SSL certs for an express.js server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804202/how-do-i-setup-a-ssl-certs-for-an-express-js-server)

If the servers are on the same hostname (just a different port), then you won't need another SSL certificate; if the servers are on a different hostname (e.g. a subdomain) *and* your SSL certificate isn't a wildcard one, then you will need another certificate.

Speaking about the port... It's true that HTTPS *by default* runs on 443, but you're free to change it as you want. Just remember to specify it, for example: https://example.com:8443/

Comment: Can you tell me please, How to enable ssl on node as well. Do i need to use same certificate or another certificate. As for my knowledge ssl will work on 443 and node is on other port :8124

Comment: Do you use Express? Can i see the code in app.js that creates the Node server?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to enable ssl on node is to use a proxy in front of your application:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('key.pem').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('cert.pem').toString();
var chainCertificate = fs.readFileSync('ca.pem').toString();


httpProxy.createServer({
      target: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: ...your application port...
      },
      ssl: {
        key: privateKey,
        cert: certificate,
        ca: chainCertificate
      }
    }).listen(...the port for ssl...);
```