# How to enable https on express 4.x (with express.static)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, express

how can i integrate ssl in express:

```
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
```

in this code to enable https?:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('webcontent', {'index': ['client.html']}));

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Webserver app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

the problem is, that i use express.static. and I dont find any sulution how to use it with https.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I setup a SSL certs for an express.js server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804202/how-do-i-setup-a-ssl-certs-for-an-express-js-server)

Comment: no they are not using express.static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable HTTPS you need to do the following.

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);

app.use(express.static('webcontent', {'index': ['client.html']}));
```

Comment: and how i use express.static in this example?