# How to force the nodejs on dotcloud to use only HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, https, dotcloud

By default dotcloud allows me to access my node instance via HTTPS, but i should allow only the HTTPS and forward every HTTP request to HTTPS.

How should I do it on dotcloud platform?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dotCloud provides an additional header: x-forwarded-proto which allows you to know the proxy source.

In your code you can use req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] ( is either 'http' or 'https' ) to know the source. When it's http you can then redirect to the https.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same way as any other node.js application hosted elsewhere.

Have you tried the solutions in these answers?

[How to force SSL / https in Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605720/how-to-force-ssl-https-in-express-js)

[Automatic HTTPS connection/redirect with node.js/express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450940/automatic-https-connection-redirect-with-node-js-express)

Answer (score 0):

Works!
Thanks guys!

```
connectApp.use(function(req, res, next){
    if( req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] && req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] == "http" )
        res.redirect( 'https://' + global.config.server.address );
    else
        next();
});
```