# Express and SSL usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, express, openssl

I've purchased a Comodo SSL certificate to make SSL server with `express`. I have these files.

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
mysite.com.key
mysite.com.csr
mysite_com.crt
```

According to a lot of documents I need `.pem` files. But nobody is saying what is that .pem files?

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/ca.pem')
};
```

It'd be great if there is a tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force SSL / https in Express.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605720/how-to-force-ssl-https-in-express-js) ([this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11033289/) specifically)

Comment: According to that answer I need to create new `certrequest.csr`. But I already bought my Comodo SSL with `mysite.com.csr`

Comment: This answer may be more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/991758/

Answer (score 1):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files).  PEM is just a format than other SSL formats, and is very common.

Comodo may have already provided you a .pem file, but just named it .crt.
OR you may be able to request a .pem file in place of a DER-formatted file.
OR, you can use OpenSSL to convert from one format to another.

```
openssl rsa -inform DER -outform PEM -in mysite.com.key -out mysite.com.key.pem
openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in mysite.com.crt -out mysite.com.crt.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply start ssl OR simple way to use PEM NPM

```
var https = require('https'),
connect = require('connect'),
fs = require("fs");
var port = 3000;
var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('/key.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/cert.pem'),
ca: fs.readFileSync('/ca.pem')
};
var app = express();
/* express setting */
server = require('https').createServer(options, app),
server.listen(port);
```

[PEM](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pem) npm is easiest way to start node server with SSL
like

```
$> npm install pem

var https = require('https'),
pem = require('pem'),
express = require('express');

pem.createCertificate({days:1, selfSigned:true}, function(err, keys){
var app = express();


https.createServer({key: keys.serviceKey, cert: keys.certificate}, app).listen(443);
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand PEM NPM, can you a little explain? thanks.