# Force redirect heroku/angular app to HTTPS version

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, heroku

I have an angular 5 app which is hosted on heroku. Currently the users can access the HTTP version of the app.

How can I force the users to be redirected to HTTPS version even if they access HTTP?

**What I have tried:**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
let sslUrl;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' &&
    req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {

    sslUrl = ['https://myapp.herokuapp.com', req.url].join('');
    return res.redirect(sslUrl);
}

return next();
});
```

I have placed the above code in my node.js server but it has not worked.

**The users are unable to use the app over HTTP as they get a 403 ERROR**

Comment: A quick google search would have returned **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605720/how-to-force-ssl-https-in-express-js)**

Comment: @trichetriche I have tried what they have suggested in that answer and it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the "force-ssl-heroku" package at https://github.com/rangle/force-ssl-heroku, works like magic and very easy integrated.

Just require inside your start entry point script:

```
var forceSsl = require('force-ssl-heroku');
```

and use it like that:

```
app.use(forceSsl);
```

Deploy and enjoy.

Comment: And make sure your NODE_ENV are set to "production" in Heruko.

Comment: Does this also redirect if the user specifically types in `http://myapp.herokuapp.com` in the browser?

Comment: Sure. when you hit "myapp.herokuapp.com" in your browser it is translated into http://myapp.herokuapp.com (with http) and then the "force ssl" package identify that the "x-forwarded-proto" header is not "https" and then redirected the request to https://myapp.herokuapp.com (with https).

You can check your status codes response at https://httpstatus.io, just put your http url and you will see the status codes.