# Why is app deployed to heroku opening with HTTP on mobile by default?

Tags: node.js, heroku

When I am using desktop browser(Chrome) everything is fine, I type `appname.herokuapp.com` and I got redirected to `https://` but when I try to enter my application on mobile version of Chrome for android and I do the same thing it gets redirected to `http://` and then I have to add "`s`" to `URL`. What could be a reason behind this?
App is wrriten with react.js, node.js, express, no database.

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: @diogo.silva yes I am

Comment: Check out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31144924/8469219