# how to use response render for a url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, passwords

U am using passport Facebook to authenticate the application on success callback how to redirect to the desired URL

```
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect : '/success',
    failureRedirect: '/'
  }),
```

on success i am routing to /success

```
router.get('/success', function(req, res){
  res.render({ url:"http://localhost:8000/#/"});
});
```

if i use the above code i am getting the error has

```
Failed to lookup view "[object Object]" in views directory "D:\project1\bookish\AdminBookPublisherRefractor/app/views"
```

I actually don't know how to redirect to a url any suggestion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355366/nodejs-redirect-url

Answer (score 0):

you can simple render your view with calling path..

```
res.render('pages/about');
```