# redirecting user based on POST input node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, redirect

Is it possible to redirect the user to whatever site they put in a text box?
This is my HTML code:

```
<form method="post">
    http://<input type="text" name="url">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Node.JS code:

```
if(request.method=="POST")
{
request.on('data', function (chunk) {
  data = chunk.toString().replace("url=","")
  console.log("DATA: "+data)
});

request.on('end', function(){
  console.log("Done");
})

console.log("end")
response.writeHead(302, {'Location' : 'http://'+data})
}
```

the code prints out the data, done and then end sequentially. obviously it doesnt redirect the user. i already know how to redirect the user, but the code im using first tries to redirect the user, then reads what the user has written in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs Redirect URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355366/nodejs-redirect-url)

Comment: Why not redirect the user on the end event? By then, you should have data ready.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine,you missed **response.end()**

```
if(request.method=="POST")  
{
  request.on('data', function (chunk) {
  data = chunk.toString().replace("url=","");
   console.log("DATA: "+data)
});

  request.on('end', function(){
    console.log("Done");
 }) 
   response.writeHead(302, {'Location' : 'http://'+data});
      response.end();
     console.log("end");

   }
```