# ReferenceError: window is not defined after Ajax call trying to redirect the user

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

I am new to express with EJS.

I tried making a ajax post request for submitting to the values to the DB using.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/register',
    data: user,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }
  });

  return false;
```

This call is successful and after which the control goes to the calling function

```
var sess;

  app.post('/register',urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    var newUsr=Users(req.body).save(function(err,data){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(" back from ajax with data :::; " + data);

      console.log("step1 cleared");
      sess.registered=true;

    });
    console.log("step2 cleared");
    location.window.href = '/index2';
  });
```

I want the user to see the index page once the registration is successful, but I am getting the below error.

```
ReferenceError: location is not defined
```

I think location object is not there in node, thus this error, but again I dont know how to fix this issue, please suggest

Comment: `window` is the global object in the browser's javascript run-time. and in node the global object is called `global`, which doesn't have location

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355366/nodejs-redirect-url

Comment: Logic is all wrong. Can't create a redirect on server for browser to go to in an ajax request. Consider returning response object that tells client side code that it either needs to redirect or consume the response data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node.js you can use `res.redirect('/')`, but it works only with `GET` requests. The right way in this situation is to return response from server with redirect status code: `302` and in your ajax script check if status code equals to `302` change location.

Your code should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/register',
   data: user,
   success: function(data, textStatus, response) {
     if(response.status === 302) {
        window.location.href = '/index2';
     }
     return data;
   }
 });
```

Server side code:

```
var sess;

app.post('/register', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  sess = req.session;
  var newUsr = Users(req.body).save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(" back from ajax with data :::; " + data);

    console.log("step1 cleared");
    sess.registered = true;

    res.status(302).send('User saved successfully');
  });
});
```