# How to redirect user to a page after receiving the response from a fetch POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, fetch-api

I am writing code for a web application that send a POST request to node.js server using fetch() api of javascript. On successful request server responds with  a redirection, this redirection url is received in the fetch() api response body. After this what should I do to redirect user to this URL from fetch function.

```
fetch("/events/registration", {
          method: "POST",
          redirect:"follow",
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json , text/plain ,*/*",
            "Content-type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name,
            email,
          })
        })
.then((res)=>res.json())
.then((data)=>{console.log(data);if(data.err)alert(data.err);Response.redirect()});
```

In response that i receive in fetch api I am getting `redirect:true , url: "LinkOfRedirection/redirect"`, now what should i do to redirect user from here to the LinkOfRedirection/redirect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355366/how-to-redirect-users-browser-url-to-a-different-page-in-nodejs it may help you

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Sets the new location of the current window.
window.location = res.url;

// Sets the new href (URL) for the current window.
window.location.href = res.url;

// Assigns a new URL to the current window.
window.location.assign(res.url);

// Replaces the location of the current window with the new one.
window.location.replace(res.url);

// Sets the location of the current window itself.
self.location = res.url;

// Sets the location of the topmost window of the current window.
top.location = res.url;
```

Or you can use

```
res.redirect(301, res.url);
```

Comment: is there a way to redirect the user from the fetch api itself

Comment: fetch api doesnot have a redirect default method . Please refer to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @VishnuR When I set window.loaction=res.url how can I pass the data? I am redirecting to dashboard and all the data that need to be plotted in dashboard should be fetched from database first otherwise dashboard will show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this would be something like this:

fetch('/api/login/' , {
method : 'POST',
headers:{
'Content-Type':'application/json',
'X-CSRFToken' : csrf,
},

```
    body : JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(result => result.json())
.then(response => {
    
    if(response.status == 200){
        window.location.href = '/'
    }
    else{
        alert(response.message)
    }

})
```