# Use nextRouter in getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is there any way i can use or have access to nextRouter/history in nextjs `getInitialProps` function.

```
const ViewPost: NextPage<EditPostProps> = (props): React.ReactElement<void> => {
  const router = useRouter(); // works here 

}

ViewPost.getInitialProps = async (ctx: Context): Promise<EditPostProps> => {
  const router = useRouter(); // doesn't work 
  // ctx props doesn't have history
}
export default withRouter(ViewPost);
```

My api class receives history or router as a param hence the need for one, but i couldn't get access to one inside the getInitialProps. Pls is there anyway i can access it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`next/router` is a client-side router therefore is not accessible during server-side rendering in `getInitialProps`.

Since Next.js 9.3 `getInitialProps` is not recommended.

You can redirect a user on server-side inside `getServerSideProps`:

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async context => {
    context.res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/login' })
    context.res.end()
    return {props: {}}
}
```

Response (`context.res`) is an instance of Node.js `http.ServerResponse` class.

[GetServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#typescript-use-getserversideprops)

[http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse)

[How to redirect user's browser URL to a different page in Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355366/how-to-redirect-users-browser-url-to-a-different-page-in-nodejs)

Comment: the reason why i need one is that, my api design so far has a fallback incase of error or unautheicated acces that redirect user to login page. In normal react, i simply use creatBrowserHistory() to be able to use history.push. I couldn't find equivalent of that in nextjs . It seems to me like i can't use history or router outside component in nextjs and hence the reason i want to pass it .

Comment: @NuruSalihu, you can redirect a user or give any response within `getInitialProps` with `ctx.res` object, so you don't need a client-side router for it

Comment: do you mean i can redirect to a certain route like login using ctx.res ? Can you please give example or explain further ? Thank you ?

Comment: Your code  yielded the error Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client . It would have been perfect otherwise.

Comment: @NuruSalihu, try `getServerSideProps`. See the updated answer, I just tested it - it works.

Answer (score 2):

The router is a singleton. You can do:

```
import Router from 'next/router'
```

and then inside `getInitialProps()`:

```
Router.push('/path');
```

Comment: by using this, I'm getting an error saying `You should only use "next/router" on the client side of your app.` so that means that this method doesn't work on `getInitialProps` since it runs on server side