# NodeJS: How to redirect to an external URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have a GET `/auth` route that accept request and need to do a redirect to an external resource (let's say `https://google.com`), but instead of redirecting me to `https://google.com` it redirects me to `http:localhost:3000/api/auth/https://google.com`.

Is that possible to redirect to an external resource somehow? Cause now it searches for the path `https://google.com` in my route.

Here is my router:

```
export const loginController = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.redirect('https://google.com');
};

router.get('/login', loginController);
```

Comment: What library are you using for the server?

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355366/how-to-redirect-users-browser-url-to-a-different-page-in-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You need to use query parameters like this:

```
http:localhost:3000/api/auth?redirectUrl=https://google.com
```

```
export const loginController = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const { redirectUrl } = req.query
  res.redirect(redirectUrl);
};
```