# How to redirect to another page through backend( node.js and express ) after signin and login

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, try-catch, backend

I want to redirect user to login page after successfully signing up. I am using try and catch so I am not being able to use redirect() method.

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); 
  try {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    let user = await mm.create({ name, email, password });
    res.status(200).json({success: true });
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, err: 'Appropriate error message' });
  }
});
```

want to redirect to `/login`  after signing up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355366/how-to-redirect-users-browser-url-to-a-different-page-in-nodejs might be helpful for redirection. But it seems you are trying to redirect to your own domain, hence the suggested approach will be to do it from the frontend rather than from backend end. Check the api response code in frontend and do frontend logic to redirect to required page.

Comment: Hmm. I can do it from frontend but I want to know how to do it from backend.

Comment: @NirdeshSharma the backend sending a 3XX redirection response based on *something that happened in the backend* is an absolutely standard way to handle situations like these. The frontend deciding to redirect based on some action on the server is usually not. Remember that a webapp could have multiple clients attached to it, you probably want as low as possible duplication client functionality. And "follow the redirection from the server" does aid in this.

Comment: Are you sending the signup data (name, email, password) via JavaScript (Axios/fetch etc)? If you just submit the form via standard way then you can easily use `res.redirect`. I always use normal form submits for new users/signups/logins for this very reason. Otherwise, you need to send the new url along with the `res.json` and do a `location.href` which isn't as smooth.

Comment: I am using div not form.