# How to redirect user logout after destroy cookie with response.setHeader() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I've a user login system on node.js. When a user is logged in, I set a cookie to maintain the user session. When the user is logged out, I destroyed the cookie with the code below:

```
function userLogout(cookies, res) {
    let cookie = Object.values(cookies)
    , cookie1 = cookie[0]
    , cookie2 = cookie[1]
    ;

    res.setHeader(
        'Set-Cookie',
            ['cookie1=; max-age=0; path=/',
            'cookie2=; max-age=0; path=/']
    );

    res.writeHead(301, {
        Location: `./index.html`
    }).end();
}
```

The redirect code above is taken from this thread: [How to redirect user's browser URL to a different page in Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355366/how-to-redirect-users-browser-url-to-a-different-page-in-nodejs)

However, I've got this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot write headers after they are sent to the client
```

It doesn't have any problem when I set the cookie in similarity order.

Any idea how can I fixed this?

Please noted that I don't use frameworks like Express, just a plain vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
function userLogout(cookies, res) {
    let cookie = Object.values(cookies)
    , cookie1 = cookie[0]
    , cookie2 = cookie[1]
    ;

    // Set the response headers
    res.setHeader(
        'Set-Cookie',
        ['cookie1=; max-age=0; path=/',
        'cookie2=; max-age=0; path=/']
    );

    // Send the redirect response
    res.writeHead(301, {
        Location: `./index.html`
    });

    // End the response
    res.end();
}
```

Comment: Not working. Setting the response headers appeared to be worked, but still got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this. I just prevented node.js to do further processing with a simple code below:

```
userLogout(cookies, res);
return;
```

That's it.