# Redirect to different page url in Node.js (Not in express or other frameworks)

Tags: node.js

I want to redirect user from one page to another page in Node.js (plain node.js)

Real life scenario: Afer signup (example.com/sigup), after successful signup I want to redirect users to login page(example.com/login).

```
if (signUpSuccessful(request, response)) {    
    // I want to redirect to "/login" using request / response parameters.
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's simple:

```
if (signUpSuccessful(request, response)) {
    response.statusCode = 302; 
    response.setHeader("Location", "/login");
    response.end();
}
```

This will redirect your user to the `/login` URL with an `302 Found` status and finish the response. Be sure that you haven't called `response.write()` before, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way to do it is by using a [302 status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) and a location field with the target URL.

> The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing
>   a redirection.
>
> An HTTP response with this status code will
>   additionally provide a URL in the Location header field. The User
>   Agent (e.g. a web browser) is invited by a response with this code to
>   make a second, otherwise identical, request, to the new URL specified
>   in the Location field. The HTTP/1.0 specification (RFC 1945) defines
>   this code, and gives it the description phrase "Moved Temporarily".

Source: Wikipedia

```
res.statusCode = 302;
res.setHeader("Location", '/login');
res.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way :

```
res.redirect(307, '/login');
```

Find more details in the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612695/expressjs-how-to-redirect-a-post-request-with-parameters)