# node.js - Redirect to url in same window

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I want to redirect to x url(http://www.google.com for example) when the user hits a button. I already tried using [open](https://github.com/jjrdn/node-open):

```
var open = require('open');
open('http://www.google.com');
```

But that opens a new window with the requested url, so the question would be:

How can I redirect to a url into the same browser window?

Comment: are you using express? if using express then use res.redirect(url)

Comment: window.location.replace('http://www.google.com') ?

Comment: @MuhammadAli I'm not using express, but good to know. Maybe I'll just start using it.

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa I've tried that one but says window is not defined

Comment: It's not supposed to run on the server. Since you said the redirect is supposed to happen when the user clicks a button, it should be client side code.

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa actually I want it to automatically do it when the user enters x path/site into my server runing.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705024/redirect-to-different-page-url-in-node-js-not-in-express-or-other-frameworks

Comment: This question is nonsensical based on the title alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT:

After what has been specified, I think the proper answer is something like this:

```
response.writeHead(302, {
  'Location': 'url-goes-here'
  //add other headers here...
});
response.end();
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062260/nodejs-redirect-url)