# How redirect to another server with post nodejs?

Tags: node.js, http, post, express, request

Nodejs, express. I have form like this:

```
<form action="https://anothersite.com/post" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="val1">
      <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="val2">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

I need this one:

```
<form action="/mypost" method="POST">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

..that means I send empty post to page `/mypost` on my server and **question**: how to redirect to another server in backend with sending post data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExpressJS : How to redirect a POST request with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612695/expressjs-how-to-redirect-a-post-request-with-parameters)

Comment: thank you for answer. the second options `request` doesn't work, it says `Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames` as I use https://... The first options redirects, but i can not modify and set my posts in backend code. Only posts from html code.

Comment: You can refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138748/pipe-a-uploaded-file-to-a-remote-server-with-node-ideally-with-same-filename) I think this will help you.