# Pipe a uploaded file to a remote server with node (ideally with same filename)

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I want to upload a file in my app.js server , which should pipe that file to a crossdomain server like my upload.js server.

The full code can be found under the following [link](https://github.com/svenhornberg/pipeupload)

The upload.js server is working. My problem is the app.js server. Request seems to be capable of streaming files (https://github.com/request/request#streaming). But I dont get it working.
I am always getting : [Error: Invalid protocol] in my app.js.

It musst be this line:

```
fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(request.post('localhost:4000/upload'))
```

I changed post to put and in my upload.js the post method also to put, but it results in the same error.

*My Goal is to upload a file from the html page to localhost:3000/upload which pipes the file to localhost:4000/upload  (ideally with same filename) .* But I dont get it working (this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818918/nodejs-sending-uploading-a-local-file-to-a-remote-server) doesn't helped me).

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express')
    , multiparty = require('multiparty')
    , request = require('request')
    , fs = require('fs')
    , util = require('util')
    , http = require('http');

var app = express();
app.use('/static', express.static('static'));

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('static/index.html');
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next){

    //https://github.com/request/request#streaming

    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received upload:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    form.on('file', function(name,file) {

        //stream it to localhost:4000 with same name
        fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(request.post('localhost:4000/upload'))

        console.log(file.path);
    });

});

var server = app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0' ,function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Upload</h2>
  <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <button>upload</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.js:**

```
var express = require('express')
    , multiparty = require('multiparty')
    , cors = require('cors')
    , util = require('util')
    , app = express();

app.use(cors());
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

app.get('/', cors(), function(req, res, next){
    res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'});
});

app.post('/upload', cors(), function(req, res, next){
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received upload:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    form.on('file', function(name,file) {
        console.log(file);
        console.log(name);
    });

});

app.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 4000');
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated**

I believe you're missing the protocol from the url.
It should work, if you add the `http` protocol to the url:

```
fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(request.post('http://localhost:4000/upload'))
```

**Make Upload work**

When you pipe the file contents to the POST function in upload.js, the multipart form data is lost. You need to create a new POST request and pass the original file contents.

Do the following in `app.js`:

```
 form.on('file', function(name, file) {

    var formData = {
      file: {
        value:  fs.createReadStream(file.path),
        options: {
          filename: file.originalFilename
        }
      }
    };

    // Post the file to the upload server
    request.post({url: 'http://localhost:4000/upload', formData: formData});
}
```

This will also pass the original filename.
For more information see: https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads

Comment: thats removes the Invalid protocol, but the upload.js server prints no output. Maybe the request.post is no multipart/form-data. I will test this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13821169/1584115

Comment: I updated your code into https://github.com/svenhornberg/pipeupload/, but still no output in upload.js. Test it with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop  (http://postimg.org/image/wq7plmjyf/)

Comment: It works for me. When I go to http://localhost:3000/static/index.html and upload a file I can see that upload.js has received it: 



CORS-enabled web server listening on port 4000
{ fieldName: 'file',
  originalFilename: 'Screen Shot 2015-08-12 at 6.24.23 PM.png',
  path: '/var/folders/r7/w49fh_652tv89r9qqwf2hg_40000gn/T/b4Z4AEZSB95INiXy1cUH_u4n.png',
  headers:
   { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="Screen Shot 2015-08-12 at 6.24.23 PM.png"',
     'content-type': 'image/png' },
  size: 464485 }
file

Comment: okay, any idea whats different between request.post and the way the postman extension posts to localhost:4000/upload ? because if I do it with postmen I get the output as expected : { fieldName: 'file',
  originalFilename: 'hello world.txt',
  path: '/tmp/g6Jd0O-pPXi2tPOcfeP7cPHd.txt',
  headers: 
   { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="hello world.txt"',
     'content-type': 'text/plain' },
  size: 13 }
file  **lines which should output from uploadjs:(from this lines form.on('file', function(name,file) {
        console.log(file);
        console.log(name);**
    });)

Comment: The difference should be in the way the POST requests are made, however when you use the latest code above, the POST request should work. Is the latest code working on the server? I mean.. if it works for me, it should work for you as well. Maybe the changes are not deployed?

Comment: Frist thank you very much, but is your postet output really from this line https://github.com/svenhornberg/pipeupload/blob/master/upload.js#L25 ?
Because I wrote a python server, which also not get any files. with postman it gets a file.

Comment: yes, it is. I start the app.js and the upload.js servers. Then I upload a sample text file.  App.js saves the file under '/var/folders/r7/w49fh_652tv89r9qqwf2hg_40000gn/T/3mAvM3mraBIv8etf4jb13cOt.txt; Then in the second console(upload.js) I see: { fieldName: 'file',
  originalFilename: 'testfile.txt',
  path: '/var/folders/r7/w49fh_652tv89r9qqwf2hg_40000gn/T/xDU83ZuLOpkJCZkQer4t25q8.txt',
  headers:
   { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="testfile.txt"',
     'content-type': 'text/plain' },
  size: 6 }
file;   i.e. the file has been re-uploaded to the upload.js server

Comment: okay, i mark your answer as right, but just for info which node version are you using ?

Comment: Thanks. I would be happy to make it work for you as well. I'm using node v0.12.5 on mac os

Comment: btw. I noticed that the request package is missing from the project dependencies. I had to add it with: npm install request --save

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem but I wanted to stream the file directly to the remote server instead of saving it locally first. Here's my modifications to get streaming to work:

```
app.post('/upload', function(request, response, next) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.on('part', function(formPart) {
        var contentType = formPart.headers['content-type'];

        var formData = {
            file: {
                value: formPart,
                options: {
                    filename: formPart.filename,
                    contentType: contentType,
                    knownLength: formPart.byteCount
                }
            }
        };

        requestJs.post({
            url: 'http://localhost:4000/upload',
            formData: formData,

            // These may or may not be necessary for your server:
            preambleCRLF: true,
            postambleCRLF: true
        });
    });

    form.on('error', function(error) {
        next(error);
    });

    form.on('close', function() {
       response.send('received upload');
    });

    form.parse(request);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually can do `stream.pipe(request.post(url));`, and then on the another server your `req` variable will have a stream-like behavior, so you should be able to `req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));`.

Use `req.params` on your route to preserve the filename.

Example code for server one (use some hashing like md5 to validate your request):

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(path);

const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5')
    .update(`${filename}${secret}`)
    .digest('hex').toUpperCase();

const url = `http://${host}/upload/${md5}/${filename}`;

const r = request.post(url, (err, resp, body) => {});

stream.pipe(r);
```

Example code for server two:

```
router.post('/upload/:md5/:filename', function(req, res, next) {
    const { md5, filename } = req.params;

    const check = crypto.createHash('md5')
        .update(`${filename}${secret}`)
        .digest('hex').toUpperCase();

    if (md5 !== check) {
        res.writeHead(403);
        res.end('403');
        return;
    }

    req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));

    req.on('end', next);
});
```