# nodejs upload files to a remote server with Multer?

Tags: node.js, multer

With Express and Multer, we can upload file to the server where nodejs is deployed. Then how can we upload files to a remote server?

Comment: Follow this Url. It might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139236/8686459

Answer (score 1):

With multer, its really simple. Pass multer as a middleware to your router.
For example, if you want to upload your file to your endpoint /uploadfile

```
app.post('/uploadfile', multer_middleware, function(req, res){
    res.end("uploaded");
});
```

multer_middleware would be like this.

```
var multer_middleare = multer({ dest: './path_to_storage',
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
        // after file is uploaded, upload it to remote server
        var filename = file.name;

        request({
            method: 'PUT',
            preambleCRLF: true,
            postambleCRLF: true,
            uri: 'http://remote-server.com/upload',
            auth: {
                'user': 'username',
                'pass': 'password',
                'sendImmediately': false
            },
            multipart: [
                { body: fs.createReadStream('./path_to_storage/' + filename) }
            ]
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                return console.error('upload failed:', error);
            }
            console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
        })
    });
```

After the file is uploaded, you can use HTTP client like [request](https://github.com/request/request) to upload it to remote server.

Don't forget to import multer at the beginning of your file

```
var multer  = require('multer');
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more details. In this way, can it only upload files to the server where node.js runs? I run node.js in my laptop, and I want to upload file to a remote server, can multer do that? If so, where and how can I put the url, username and password to connect to remote server?

Answer (score -1):

You can use heroku to deploy it, and use Cloudinary to upload them to the cloud.

```
//requiring cloudinary and multer

const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
const cloudinaryStorage = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');
const multer = require('multer');

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET
});

var storage = cloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary,
  folder: 'assets', // The name of the folder in cloudinary
  allowedFormats: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gid', 'pdf'],
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname); // The file on cloudinary would have the same name as the original file name
  }
});


const uploadCloud = multer ({ storage: storage})
//const uploadCloud = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

module.exports = uploadCloud;
```