# How to resize the image and convert to buffer then store to mysql using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Because When I upload above 2mb size of image in node js using mysql

"not upload throw some issues"

> "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes"

I am using npm module `multer` for file upload. My code for upload image is as follows:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max\_allowed\_packet' bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes)

Comment: I would recommend you save your uploads as files rather than in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify in the my.ini or ~/.my.cnf file

> max_allowed_packet=512M

You can insert this line under [mysqld] section.

After this change please Restart the mysql once.
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks bro . any changes in nodejs code ?.. because some restriction to use my.ini or ~/.my.cnf file in sql

Comment: In node js , are you using express ?

Comment: now i changed but again show same error "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes" .

Comment: you have to change .ini file OR one more if you can use streaming for upload the image. Can you share your code ?

Comment: OK Deep. Thank you so much

Comment: are you using multer for upload ?

Comment: you have only two options 1.) update .ini file 2.) use streaming module like express-busboy or busboy etc. to upload your file. It will upload your file in stream

Comment: OK Deep. I will modified

Comment: Deep now i modified in the my.ini[max_allowed_packet=512M] file in my php myadmin. But again occur same error "a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes"

Comment: have you restarted mysql service after that?

Comment: no. now i change my idea using "Sharp" Module and i try to resize image  but still not resize

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true, limit:'50mb'}));

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138748/pipe-a-uploaded-file-to-a-remote-server-with-node-ideally-with-same-filename

Comment: Deep now i analyzing !

Comment: ok, please share your answer or solution when ever you will get that. I also wants to know.