Node JS - handling client request timeout
I am writing a simple endpoint in Node JS which takes the file stream from the caller and sends it to another API. Basically this API acts as a delegator for a file upload scenario.
File Provide -> My endpoint -> File Receiver
The file provider calls my API and provides the raw stream of file which I am directly sending it to receiver. I don't want to store it anywhere. Now the problem is file provider has been setup with a timeout of 300 seconds. That is, it continues to give me the data stream only for 300 sec and after that I get "ECONNRESET". Obviously the file upload will fail. Which is fine. But I am unable to handle this failure. I want to handle this error and send a notification to uploader. I have tried this but it does not work. That is, code in the error block never executes. How can I get this to work?
app.put('/upload', (req, res) => {
   
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
    // code to send the data to file receiver 
})


share the the code that pipes incoming  stream to provider

This post may answer the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138748/pipe-a-uploaded-file-to-a-remote-server-with-node-ideally-with-same-filename
