# NODEJS - Reroute on same Url

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am kind of stuck in something. Please help me

The problem i want to solve is -

I am getting some post parameters and i want to route based on those parameters in NodeJs. Now the issue is when i use switch case to route on base of the post params rerouting is not happening.

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var method = req.body.method;
    switch (method) {
        case 'register_user':
            router.post('/', userController.registerUser);
            break;
        case 'user_login':
            router.post('/', userController);
            break;
}
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612695/expressjs-how-to-redirect-a-post-request-with-parameters

Answer (score 2):

Your rerouting code inside switch context just appends more middlewares on the path `/`, not actually do the route as you think.

Revise like this:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var method = req.body.method;
    switch (method) {
        case 'register_user':
            // returned since you want route to the function
            return userController.registerUser(req, res, next);
            break;
        case 'user_login':
            return userController(req, res, next);
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hank,
But i wana reroute only since i want to execute multiple functions one by one like this,
router.post('/', a,b,c); where a,b,c are functions.. Doing it your way will make the code messy

Comment: Redirect will result in another request and may increase traffic to load balanacer

Comment: I don't know if [ES6 generator](http://eladnava.com/write-synchronous-node-js-code-with-es6-generators/) meet your need. You may  need to rewrite sub callbacks as generator and use [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) properly.