# How to redirect to a url along with making a post request to it in node js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, post, express

Basically what will happen is my angular page will make a post request to my express/node js application.

I want express on receiving that post request from angular to redirect to an other URL and also along with redirecting, want to POST data to that web page.
How will I use `res.redirect("")` in node js to also post some data.

Node js Code:

```
app.post('/ur-book',function(req,res){
    var data=...;
    res.redirect('/abcd');
});
```

I want to post data on /abcd and redirect to it.

other url will not be in my node app. It will be on a different website.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do this is to create a function that handles request to /abcd and call that function from /ur-book like so

```
function handleAbcd(req, res) {
    console.log(req.myData); // output will be undefined if it's not comming from /ur-book
    res.json({});
}

app.post('/abcd',handleAbcd);

app.post('/ur-book',function(req,res){

    // if you need to add some data you can add them to req.body or even your own for example req.myData
    req.myData = 'hello';
    handleAbcd(req, res);

});
```

Comment: But th other url will not be in my node app. It will be on a different website.

Comment: @MohammedGadiwala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612695/expressjs-how-to-redirect-a-post-request-with-parameters