# How to Redirect url with post data using http module in node.js

Tags: node.js, http, http-post, http-redirect

I have to redirect url i.e https://domain.com/micro  with email_id=san@gmail.com as body through post/get request.

I know that We can do it by passing parameter to url with get method.but I dont want to pass in url for that I have pass as body.

this is my endpoint,

```
var body1 = JSON.stringify({
        email_id:'san@gmail.com',
        link_id:'34sd'
}); 
function read(request,respone){
response.statusCode = 307;      
        response.writeHead(307,{Location: 'https://domain.com/micro'});                     
        response.end(body1);
}
```

Please can you suggest me on same .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612695/expressjs-how-to-redirect-a-post-request-with-parameters

Comment: But that is express module ,i want to do with http module.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js