# How to forward Post request in moleculerjs (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, moleculer

I already tried using `ctx.$location=“/targetpath”` but the forwarded request change to get Method, not the original post method.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a Moleculer issue. You should set 307 status code to keep method. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612942/129346

```js
ctx.meta.$statusCode = 307;
ctx.meta.$location = "/targetpath";
```