# How to allow http in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https

I have a site that use https. i'm using node.js
I want to add url in mysite. 
The url using http, when i try it doens't allow,
it cause im using https.

is it possible to allow http in https using node.js
this is my code

```
<iframe src="http://url/" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto">
<p>Your browser doesn't support iframe</p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having mixed content (http AND https) on an https page kinda defeats the purpose, so I'd advice not to. Some browsers will break or fire annoying alerts to the user when you do.

In case you really, really want to (or are just willing to learn about ports and weird configurations over the conventions), [you might like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453782/nodejs-http-and-https-over-same-port).

Comment: thank you. i alreeady read about it but i have some problem with it, i dont use .pem neither cert.pem. is there any solution about it. @enrique-ramirez

Comment: I don't think the encoding of your certificate changes the steps to follow, so it shouldn't be a problem. @agstwn21