# How redirect http to https

Tags: node.js, http, ssl, amazon-web-services, https

I install an ssl certificate, and is working when i try open my site in `https://`, the problem is when i try access in `http://`, the page will stay loading forever.

I am using node.js in an ubuntu ec2 instance, in amazon web services.

Where should i forward the http to https? In the server by the console, or in the route 53?

http (not ok):

http://goo.gl/AlJ5RR

https (ok):

http://goo.gl/rKYW9A

Answer (score 0):

HTTP to HTTPS redirection is the responsibility of node.js or whatever HTTP front end your are using (nginx for example).

This question [Automatic HTTPS connection/redirect with node.js/express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450940/automatic-https-connection-redirect-with-node-js-express) has a good set of answers for both node.js and nginx.

As you are deploying to Amazon EC2, do not forget to open TCP 80 in the Security Group attached to your instance.