# HTTP redirect to HTTPS in a different port

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, https, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect every http request to an https server. [This works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23977269/2573422) if the port of the https server is the 443. However if I try to redirect to a different port it doesn't happen. Here is my code:

```
http.createServer(function(req,res){
    var host = req.headers['host'],
        url = req.url;
        res.writeHead(301,
            {"Location": "https://" + host + ":"+SERVER.SPORT + url})
        res.end()
}).listen(SERVER.PORT)

https.createServer(SERVER.HTTPS_OPTIONS,app).listen(SERVER.SPORT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `host` most likely already includes the port number.

You can make sure if you change this:

```
var host = req.headers['host']
```

to:

```
var host = req.headers['host'].split(':')[0];
```

Also add some logging:

```
console.log("https://" + host + ":"+SERVER.SPORT + url);
```

to see what the URL that you're building looks like.

You can also want to use the `url` module to work with URLs instead of manually concatenating strings to avoid mistakes like that. See:

- https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

In any case add some logging to know what the URL that you're building looks like. Also test it with curl:

```
curl -v http://localhost:1234
```

to see what headers are returned.

Comment: I had that in a log and didn't notice. I felt really dumb after your answer they even have a nice representation of the url in the [api](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_strings_and_url_objects)! 
But If I explicitly asked for the `example.com:80` the method found in other answers (and that I used) would also fail. Which means that this only works because of the hidden default ports?