# how to redirects HTTP to HTTPs using iptables and parse-server (Parse Server)

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, iptables, parse-server

I'm dealing with SSL/https on my server.

I configured two ports, one for HTTP (4000) and another for HTTPS (9080) using iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -t natL -n --line-number
1    REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 redir ports 9080
2    REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 4000
```

**How can I tell Parse Server to redirects all traffic coming http to use https?**

I did previously a similar configuration using expressJS but it is not working with Parse Server, this is the code I previously used:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    return res.redirect(['https://domainName.tv', req.url].join(''));
});
```

Here is my app index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var SimpleSendGridAdapter = require('parse-server-sendgrid-adapter');
var stripe = require("stripe");
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');


var databaseUri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev';

if (!databaseUri) {
    console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/domainName.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/domainName.crt')
};

var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: 'xN6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmx',
    masterKey: 'egxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdn',
    javascriptKey: 'O2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxYy', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
    serverURL: 'https://localhost:9080/parse',
    restAPIKey: 'lxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxN',
    appName: 'domainName.TV',
    publicServerURL: 'https://domainName.tv/parse',
    emailAdapter: SimpleSendGridAdapter({
        apiKey: 'SG.SbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMxc',
        fromAddress: 'team@domainName.tv',
    }),
    liveQuery: {
        classNames: ["UsPrIn", "Event"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
    }
});

var app = express();

// redirect all http requests to https
// THIS IS NOT WORKING!!!!
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    return res.redirect(['https://domainName.tv', req.url].join(''));
});

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 9080;

var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server running on SSL port ' + port + '.');
});

var httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(4000, function() {
    console.log('parse-server running on port 4000.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpsServer);
```

My solutions is similar to this one but I'm using Parse Server: [Automatic HTTPS connection/redirect with node.js/express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450940/automatic-https-connection-redirect-with-node-js-express)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in case someone is in need: req.secure

this is the code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if(!req.secure && (req.headers.host !== 'localhost:7777')) {
        return res.redirect(['https://mydomain.tv', req.url].join(''));
    }
    next();
});
```