# Why cannot I redirect my React app on Heroku from http to https?

Tags: reactjs, express, ssl, heroku

I have an app on Heroku that was created using `create-react-app`. Just today, I got an SSL cert using Heroku's automated(-ish) SSL cert process ExpeditedSSL, and the documentation then suggests rerouting all http requests to https.

I have a server.js file and express I use just to attempt to run middleware and then serve my React app.

I know the SSL cert is working as if I go to https://myapp.com I see my Heroku app, but when I go to http://myapp.com it is not redirected to the https version of my Heroku app.

I have tried many, many `solutions` today from StackOverflow, Google, and otherwise and none of the the solutions have worked for me. I don't get any errors, either. It just doesn't work.

Attempt using `https library`:

```
const https = require("https");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

https.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Another attempt using `heroku-ssl-redirect`:

```
var sslRedirect = require('heroku-ssl-redirect');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// enable ssl redirect
app.use(sslRedirect(['production'], 301));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https'){
    res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Attempt using `x-forward-proto`:

```
const express = require('express');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

var forceSsl = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
    return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
  }
  return next();
};

if (env === 'production') {
  app.use(forceSsl);
}

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

I've also attempted a number of random node installs from various blogs and SO posts, and nothing has worked. Without any errors I am having a hard time figuring out why this doesn't work.

Comment: You tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450940/automatic-https-connection-redirect-with-node-js-express  ?

Comment: @pritesh Yes. That is one of the things I had tried. Thanks for the response, though!

Comment: @smkarber Did you ever figure out a better solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try adding the following to the header of your index.html file

```
<script>
var host = "www.URL.com" || "URL.com";
if ((host == window.location.host) && (window.location.protocol != "https:")){
window.location.protocol = "https";
}
</script>
```

I was dealing with a similar issue and this allowed me to resolve it. Placing it in the header ensures that the script will run before any of your bundled JavaScript, but I suppose it would work above your bundle.js file

Comment: Strangely, I needed to do an `else if()` with each `host` string being declared independently to get this to work, which makes no sense, but nevertheless was the case. e.g. `let longUrl = 'www.url.com'` `let shortUrl = 'url.com'`... `if (longUrl === ....)` ... `else if (shortUrl === .... )`.

Comment: @misterfoxy just want to say personal "Thank you" as your answer saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: I'm just curious if handling this at the application layer has any consequences?  Indexed differently?  SEO?

Comment: @RubenMurray & Misterfoxy you guys saved me. I also had to do the two else if as shown above

Comment: The `else if` change is a requirement because the `var` is declared as an `||`. `www.url.com` == `url.com || 'www.url.com'` is `false`, but `url.com` == `url.com || 'www.url.com'` is `true`

My comment 3 years ago missed this.

I've submitted an edit to the existing solution which should be clearer, though the more I read it I'm not sure exactly why the `url` is required at all. Why not just always forward to `https` if the protocol isn't set. The url should always be as expected given it's your own site.

ALSO: There is an answer below which is apparently better.

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATED and SECURE solution below:**

**Since you are deploying your react app via Heroku using create-react-app and it's buidlpack (recommended, if you are not: create-react-app-buildpack)**. So as the official docs says:

The web server may be [configured via the static buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static#configuration).

The config file `static.json` should be committed at the root of the repo. It will not be recognized, if this file in a sub-directory

The default `static.json`, if it does not exist in the repo, is:

```json
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

### HTTPS-only

Enforce secure connections by automatically redirecting insecure requests to **https://**, in `static.json`:

```json
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  },
  "https_only": true
}
```

The method by @misterfoxy works but is not the right way!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `express-https-redirect`.

Install with:

```
npm install express-https-redirect --save
```

Then you should be able to do something like:

```
const express = require('express');
const httpsRedirect = require('express-https-redirect');
const app = express();
app.use('/', httpsRedirect());
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
        console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get home. Thanks.

Comment: This also seems to fail. If I type in the url sans `https` or using `http`, it just goes to the non-secure url. With `https` in the url it works as one would hope, but I cannot get it to redirect from http to https.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your index.html file
Place it in the header, so it would run before other scripts

```
<script>
const domain1 = "www.example.com";
const domain2 = "example.com";
const host = window.location.host;
if ((domain === host || domain2 === host) && (window.location.protocol !== "https:")){
  window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me React on Heroku

Buildpack
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

root/static.json

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  },
  "https_only": true
}
```

https://youtu.be/LAjj_kzqbjw