# How to fix google cloud ssl issue

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, ssl-certificate, gcloud, google-appengine-node

I pointed a new custom domain to a Google App Engine Standard Environment project and edited the DNS records per Google's instructions, and it seems to be redirected properly.

When I go to

```
www.mydomain.com
```

with its supposedly activated certificate, I still get

> connection is not secure

in the browser. If I go to

```
mydomain.com
```

it gets redirected to

```
www.mydomain.com
```

with the same result.

But when I directly enter

```
https ://www.mydomain.com
```

it display the website and with connection is secure. Let me know the reason for this and how to fix this issue?

I used below command

```
gcloud app domain-mappings list
```

and it displays that there is a ssl certificate id. But the above issue is still there.

Comment: I had the same issue.Still not fixed

Comment: Did you use the `secure: always` option in your `app.yaml` handler(s)? Can you show your app.yaml content?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends on which language and which environment you're using.

**Node.js and flexible environment**

It looks like you are using Node.js, in the case of Node.js for both standard and flexible environments, and for flexible environment users of all languages, **you need to handle the redirect in your application's code**. How you do this might change depending on if you're using a Framework. Check out the [answer for how to do this with an Express app as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458587/1354939).

**First generation standard environment**

For the standard environment Python 2.7, PHP 5.5, and Go 1.9, you need to instruct App Engine to always use the secure connection for requests by updating your `app.yaml` configuration file's handlers to look something like:

```
handlers:
- url: /.* 
  script: main.app  # <- Python example
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

Comment: this is not worked for me.I'm using node js.And the above added link is 7 years old one