# App-engine custom domain not defaulting to HTTPS

Tags: google-app-engine, https, google-cloud-platform, custom-domain

I have just set up a custom domain for my Google App Engine, using a domain I bought from GoDaddy. Then I transferred the nameservers to Cloud DNS and inserted the DNS records as the cloud documentation suggested into the cloud DNS record set, and it is working fine.

However, the problem is that when I use the custom domain, it doesn't default to the HTTPS version of the site, I have to manually type in HTTPS (ie I can't just go to `example.com`, I have to go to `https://example.com)`.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: You haven't indicated if you followed the instructions or the troubleshooting steps in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix google cloud ssl issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148472/how-to-fix-google-cloud-ssl-issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**App Engine standard environment**

Add the following two lines to your `app.yaml`:

```
secure: always
redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

**App Engine flexible environment**

You will need to setup HTTPS redirects from within your web server app. Each server `node.js`, `django`, `Flask`, etc. has their own method of handling HTTPS as the only protocol.

Comment: Thank you! I would never have known this. Works like a charm.

Comment: Are any other Java developers frustrated that `appengine-web.xml` seems to compile into an `app.yaml` but we can't setup the `secure: always` and `redirect_http_response_code: 301` from our `appengine-web.xml`?

Comment: For rookies like myself - code has to be under url tag:
`- url: /.*  
  script: auto  
  secure: always  
  redirect_http_response_code: 301`

Answer (score 1):

For rookies like myself :-
In app.yaml file you already have first 2 lines of following code. Add last to lines under it:

```
- url: /.*  
  script: auto  
  secure: always  
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

Reference : [app.yaml file documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref)
All urls will get redirected for https secure connections