# How can I disable http access to a GCP Cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

A GCP cloud function that takes a `HTTP` trigger can be accessed via `http` and `https` transports.
Is there a way to disable the `http` endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there is no functionality to achieve this from the start.

What you could do, is to redirect any incoming request from HTTP to HTTPS from inside the function. I don't know in which language you are working with but there is a [good discussion on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49176816/8889821).