# key for pem file in node js heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, apple-push-notifications, pem

I got the following code for apple push service:

```
  agent
.set('cert file', join(__dirname, 'cert.pem'))
.set('key file', join(__dirname, 'key.pem'))
.enable('sandbox');
```

When I run my server on localhost, I enter pem key, and server starts working.

How can I set it to be entered automatically, because I deploy it on heroku I do `git push heroku master` and server fails because I didn't enter pem key.

Comment: Can you generate non-password protected pem files?

Comment: @leesei Is it possible? it asked me for password

Comment: Try to press enter when prompted for it.

Comment: @leesei I delete it doing this `openssl rsa -in key.pem -out key.pem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used these commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -x509 -days 7300 -out certificate.pem
```

I used them in Node.js HTTPS server.

See [Enabling HTTPS on express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js)

Answer (score 3):

Does the library you use to send notifications support passing the string data of the certificate/key? You can try adding the contents as environment variables on heroku using the `heroku config` command. For instance:

`heroku config:set CERT_DATA='content of the file'`

You can then reference `CERT_DATA` in your code rather than reading the file. You will also need a way to set the environment variables during development, but I'm not familiar enough with the tools that are available to suggest how to do that.