# expressjs API with https

Tags: node.js, rest, express, https, haproxy

I want create a REST API using nodejs and with expressjs, i want to deploy this on my VPS server, i've and haproxy on front of this VPS.

My question how to secure this with HTTPS protocol? I mean I need to buy a https certificate or I can use on self assign, cause that is only for secure the API routes. I never use HTTPS on my server before, I how if i need secure my website with https i need a public certificate however for API I think that is no need right?

Also I down know you to secure this on haproxy or on client side.

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling HTTPS on express.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js)

Comment: If you use a self signed certificate, then any browser will report your site as untrusted unless the user manually tells the browser to trust your site.  If it is programmatic agents accessing an API, they will also report your site as untrusted and what behavior they get depends upon their SSL library.

Comment: Thanks for your response, did you know any provider where i can buy a certificate? I just need to accessing the API I have google this and i dont know how some one is very expensive and other are very low price!