# Express.js HTTPS not starting server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, express, https

I'm trying to configure HTTPS for my Express server. I found the following code from [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js).

```
console.log("Test 1");
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
console.log("Test 2");
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
console.log("Test 3");
httpServer.listen(8080);
console.log("Test 4");
httpsServer.listen(8443);
console.log("Test 5");
```

Problem is the only thing that appears in the console is `Test 1` and `Test 2`. Nothing after that line seems to be running. I basically just want the same Express app to run on both HTTP and HTTPS.

In the past I just used `server = app.listen(port);` to start the Express server.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The Node app continues to run with no errors but just doesn't print those final `console.log` statements.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('ssl/servertest.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('ssl/servertest.crt', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
```

[servertest.key](https://gist.github.com/fishcharlie/c070b4787f647b3ea10dc2b3a5806cea) and [servertest.crt](https://gist.github.com/fishcharlie/b3bd63104c1d6b75716359e568c02500).

Note: I know putting those online and making them public is a bad idea. Just using it for example. Before going into production I'm going to regenerate the SSL keys.

Comment: All that code in node would get executed asynchronously, so I'm assuming you have an error in your createServer(credentails   what's have you got in credentials?

Comment: @Keith No error was logged in the terminal or anything

Comment: Strange,.. Does the node App stop, do you have valid key & cert in your credentials?.. I use Express HTTPS without any problems.  Could you knock up a quick demo of what you've done?

Comment: @Keith Just made a few edits to try to describe it better.

Comment: Your private key is password protected..

Comment: @Keith Great looks like that worked! One more question. I'm currently using `server.close`. I can just use `httpServer.close` and `httpsServer.close` since I don't have server anymore correct? Also feel free to leave an answer and I will up vote and accept it.

Comment: Yes, you can just do httpServer.close(),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the private key was password protected.

On my system I was getting the error,

```
Error: error:0906A068:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad password read
```

not sure why you wasn't, maybe it's node version.

Here you have 2 options, either remove the password from the key using openSSL, or supply the password to the options via the passphrase option.