# How to enable SSL connection a NodeJS (Express) based Server

Tags: node.js, ssl

Following is the script I found on NodeJS Official Website:

```
// curl -k https://localhost:8000/
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

I'm completely new to SSL thing. I read some tutorials on how to enable SSL on Nodejs but still quite not confident with the process.

I have a domain name (Godaddy), SSL (Namecheap) and Cloud Server (Digital Ocean with an application deployed on HTTP prefix).

Whenever I open my Login page of my website, Google Chrome mark it as "Not secure" so I wanted to add SSL to the website.

What things I need to do on the NodeJS server (Express) and what things I need to do on Namecheap? What will be the sequence of doing that? What are cmd lines to generate .pem .csr files?

I'm didn't found and comprehensive guide laying down all the steps in a concise manner so just laid down the steps concisely (if possible) with the links to the resources for further digging.

And also, how can I use express framework to create https server in liue of above script?

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js

Answer (score 0):

That script is correct for setting the certs for your https. If your site is public, as it seems, then you'll want to buy certs from your ssl service, Namecheap in your example. Then you would move them to your host and reference them in the options object in your example. However, you can generate your own ssl certs and that will work as well. Though, any users will be warned that they're not trusted since you self signed/created them. I suggest going with the Namecheap option.

Note: You only have an https server in your example and anyone attempting to access your site via http will receive a blank page. You'll need to also create an http server, via the following:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(...);
```

I would suggest having the http server simply redirect to the https url.

Answer (score 0):

My code and error is here:

no such directory found error:

```
  key: fs.readFileSync('../private.key'),

  cert: fs.readFileSync('../public.cert')
```

error, no such directory found

```
  key: fs.readFileSync('./private.key'),

  cert: fs.readFileSync('./public.cert')
```

***Working code should be***

```
key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/private.key', 'utf8'),

cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public.cert', 'utf8')
```

***Complete https code is:***

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

// readFileSync function must use __dirname get current directory
// require use ./ refer to current directory.

const options = {
   key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/private.key', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public.cert', 'utf8')
};


 // Create HTTPs server.

 var server = https.createServer(options, app);
```

This is my ***working code*** for ***express 4.0***.

express 4.0 is very different from 3.0 and others.

4.0 you have /bin/www file, which you are going to add https here.

"npm start" is standard way you start express 4.0 server.

readFileSync() function should use ***__dirname*** get current directory

while require() ***use ./*** refer to current directory.

***First you put private.key and public.cert file under /bin folder, 
It is same folder as WWW file***.