# How to set up HTTPS using Lets Encrypt, Node, and Express 4

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, https, lets-encrypt

## What I've Done

I used `certbot` to certify that I own my domain, which generated several `.pem` files. The certificates are listed here: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-are-my-certificates

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js/11745114#11745114) which makes sense and matches all of the other information I'm getting from Googling around, but when I do this and run node I can't connect to my site using https. Http works fine as it always has.

My server is express.js + node.js and I'm not using a reverse proxy like nginx. It's running on Ubuntu on Google Cloud Platform.

The relevant code is:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/troywolters.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/troywolters.com/fullchain.pem', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var app = express();

// Lots of other express stuff (app.use()'s)

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpServer.listen(80);
httpsServer.listen(443);
```

## What doesn't work

When I try to connect to my site using https://troywolters.com the connection times out and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When remoted into your server can you make a local request to 443 port to make sure your node.js app is handling the request correctly? If it does then you most likely have a iptable issue/port being blocked. If it doesn't then there's something wrong with your app.

Comment: @Darkrum Sorry, how would I do that? I tried looking at `ping` but it seems to not do https, only ECHO, and curl just hangs when I do `curl --request https://troywolters.com`. When I do `curl --request https://127.0.0.1` though it says: curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (troywolters.com) does not match target host name '127.0.0.1' so maybe that's a good sign?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem was that my hosting platform (Google Cloud Platform) did not allow port 443 through the firewall in the default configuration. Running

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-https --description "Incoming https allowed." --allow tcp:443
```

allowed incoming traffic through port 443 and fixed the problem.

Thank you to Michael Hampton from Server Fault for the tip.