Express-session creates new session every request on prod only and it works fine on dev
I am working on ecommerce site where I want to save carts for all visitors using the session id generated with express-session. On dev mode it works perfectly but on prod the session id get regenerated with every request. I added app.set("trust proxy", 1) but it didn't help me to fix the session id between requests.
Here is my config for the session middleware:
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    }),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      sameSite: "None",
    },
  })
);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   console.log("Session ID:", req.session.id);
   req.session.visited = true;
   next();
 });
app.set("trust proxy", 1);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


Can you please see these two things. 1) That in a fresh (new) single request-response cycle, the cookie reaches at the Browser, and gets stored there with the session ID. 2) And in the subsequent request-response cycle, the Browser sends the same cookie back and the server receives this. If the server does not receives the cookie from Browser, it will create another session Id. For more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894789/node-js-express-session-creating-new-session-id-every-time-i-refresh-or-access-t

thank you so much for your help. I found out that the browser was not sending the cookie back to the server.

Thank you for your update. Please see if setting this works : withCredentals:true. Something like this if it is axios : axios.get('http://localhost:8080/getDetails',{
headers:{
withCredentials:true,
               }

}); It is there in the post cited.

The XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property is a boolean value that indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials such as cookies, authentication headers or TLS client certificates. Setting withCredentials has no effect on same-origin requests. Citation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Hi, Is the issue still persisting ?

Hi, No I have solved the problem. Thank you.

Hi, Thank you for your update. If you will, kindly update your question with the answer you have found so that this question will not remain open. It would help this forum to provide reference to all other info seekers like you and me.
