# Start NodeJS through pm2 with sudo privileges to access SSL keys

Tags: node.js, ssl, ubuntu-16.04, file-permissions, pm2

I have a digital ocean droplet running Ubuntu 16.04. I followed [this guide](https://itnext.io/node-express-letsencrypt-generate-a-free-ssl-certificate-and-run-an-https-server-in-5-minutes-a730fbe528ca) to use HTTPS with my NodeJS server.

### In short

I used certbot to create an SSL certificate, which meant that at **this directory** `/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/`, 3 files were created:

1. privkey.pem
2. cert.pem
3. chain.pem

So in my server code, I have to fetch these files, which I do:

```
// Certificate
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/chain.pem', 'utf8');
```

### The Problem

When I tried to run my server using the command `node server`, or using `pm2 start server` I got this error message:

```
  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/mywebsite/lib/server-configurations.js:13:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem' }
```

### BUT

When I tried launching it using `sudo node server` it **did** work without any problems.

#### Small Notice

I know I can change the permissions on the files but I would rather not do that as I have read multiple times that it is better not to change the permissions on these files.

#### And most importantly...

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Why is it better to not change the permissions on these files instead of launching your app as root ?

Comment: @TGrif I do not really know, but I have seen it so many times said to not change the permissions in Linux especially for sensitive data. I am not really an expert on Linux as it is my first time managing a Linux server (or managing a server for that matter). I would love to know if you think there is no problem in changing the permissions, and if you think there is a flaw in my thinking about this.

Comment: My advice on this is to never launch your app as root. So I think you have to deal with your cert files permission in a way or another.

Answer (score 1):

I did change permissions according to [Let's encrypt SSL couldn't start by "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/privkey.pem'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078083/lets-encrypt-ssl-couldnt-start-by-error-eacces-permission-denied-open-et) 
That worked for running

node file.js

Still now pm2's process somehow can't access the certs even though it should be running as the same user as node... perplexing.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. After changing permissions I can run the program myself, but PM2 cannot, even though it's supposed to be running it as my user. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I had the same issue, rebooted the machine, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this certbot script](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-use-certs-in-non-root-services/2690/8).

[More info on certbot renewals](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates) might be helpful, as well as other solutions for this issue [on the Let's Encrypt forums](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-use-certs-in-non-root-services/2690).