# node.js Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'privkey.pem'

Tags: node.js, socket.io, certificate, pem, wss

I'm setting secure websocket over node.js using socket.io:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var server = https.createServer({ 
    key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/host/privkey.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/host/fullchain.pem") 
});
server.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
....
```

And when run server:

```
user@admin:/var/www/host/node.js_ws$ node server.js
```

I'm getting

```
node:internal/fs/utils:344
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/etc/letsencrypt/live/host/privkey.pem'
```

I already sudo chmod / chown 755 the folder and pem files there, but no chance. Where is my bad?

Comment: what happens when you do `cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/host/privkey.pem` as the same user?

Comment: Permission denied

Comment: same here. stuck

Comment: The top answer listed for this question should fix the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903098/1452308