# How to setup HTTPS on Express, Express Generator

Tags: node.js, express

How to setup HTTPS on Express, Express Generator, how to redirect http to https? Do we need to create both different server for that or we can redirect it with just one server.

Comment: follow this link, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745114/7266810

Answer (score 0):

This would be more on the reverse proxy engine you're using, or if you want a simple solution, simply use CloudFlare.

Comment: Can you please explain reverse proxy engine? How I can use it?

Comment: @Navit https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04