# Getting a https express node app to work on shared hosting

Tags: node.js, express

So I'm at a lose here and really need some direction.

I've been following Microsofts 'Introduction To NodeJS' course on edX. We had to create a *very* simple RESTful blog api using express. I've been trying to get it to run on my namecheap shared hosting.

What I've done:

- Followed [these instructions](http://vinyll.scopyleft.fr/installing-a-custom-version-of-node-on-a-shared-hosting/) to install nvm with the latest stable version of node.
- Followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js) to get my express app to work with https
- Uploaded the app to the hosting server.
- SSH'd into the hosting server, ran `npm install`.
- ran `node server.js` to start the server. Seems to start okay.
- Try navigating to my website on the port the app is listening on `https://samkeene.co.uk:3000/blog-api`
- Expecting to see "Hello World" but instead getting a timeout.

**server.js**

```
const routes = require('./routes');
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const errorhandler = require('errorhandler');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let store = {
    posts: []
};

let key = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../../ssl/keys/c07f7_003d1_ecb06ccb2afcd72cfa43b6011c82464e.key'));
let cert = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../../ssl/certs/samkeene_co_uk_c07f7_003d1_1574035199_5b90fc5e96ac0c534d2ee116af6fd342.crt'));
let options = {
    key: key,
    cert: cert
};

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(errorhandler());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.store = store;
    next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world')
});

app.get('/posts', routes.Posts.getPosts);
app.post('/posts', routes.Posts.addPost);
app.put('/posts/:postID', routes.Posts.updatePost);
app.delete('/posts/:postID', routes.Posts.removePost);

app.get('/posts/:postID/comments', routes.Comments.getComments);
app.post('/posts/:postID/comments/', routes.Comments.addComment);
app.put('/posts/:postID/comments/:commentID', routes.Comments.updateComment);
app.delete('/posts/:postID/comments/:commentID', routes.Comments.removeComment);

let server = https.createServer(options, app);

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("server starting on port : " + 3000)
});
```

The rest of the files can be found in its [git repo](https://github.com/SKeeneCode/express-blog-api). (or navigate to https://www.samkeene.co.uk/blog-api/)

Would really appreciate some help.

Edit: I decided to just try if I can get even simpler app to run:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');

let app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("hello");
    res.send('hello world')
});

app.listen(3001);
```

This runs into the same trouble! Connection timeout. I'm really at a lose here.

Comment: is it running on http? did you connect that domain on your server ip?

Comment: @MohamedSameer how can I tell? I would have thought `server = https.createServer(options, app);` ensured it was a https server?

Comment: 'did you connect that domain on your server ip? ' Sorry I'm not sure what you mean here?

Comment: https://code.lengstorf.com/deploy-nodejs-ssl-digitalocean/

Comment: follow this tutorial for hosting a node app with https ssl.

Comment: Check your server logs. There has to be something logged.

Comment: @SanSolo I see no errors being logged in the shell, and nothing I can see wrong in the raw access logs.

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do with the port you are listening on.

For http listen on port 8080

For https listen on port 443

Answer (score 0):

Was scratching my head about this one too for a while once I was on a shared hosting.

I managed to run the following by setting up a NodeJS app via cPanel with NodeJS version 9.11.2:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Howdy! req.url: '+req.url);
});
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Should send a bunch of users!');
});
app.get('/things/:name/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.send('id: ' + req.params.id + ' and name: ' + req.params.name);
});
app.listen();
```

I didn't have to care about port numbers and was able to access these end points via HTTPS too.

In your case, just remove 3001 and see if it works with your shared hosting.

Hope it helps. :)